# Mysql calculating subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a subquery for a staff take. The question is:

List  all  staff  whose  salary  is  greater  than  the average  salary,  and  show  by  how  much  their  salary is  greater  than  the  average.

I've got the first part but I can't seem to figure out how to calculate the difference between the AVG salary and salary.

So far I've got this

```
Select name from staff where salary >=(select AVG(salary) from staff)
```

how do I add the difference part?

Edit: the table columns are staffNo, name, position, salary, branchNo

Comment: That worked jaydipJ thanks it's easy when you know how and that was an easy one haha

Comment: If this helps you then you can accept it as Ans or any other Ans whichever helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this is the correct way to acheive desire result

```
Select name,Salary-(select AVG(salary) from staff)t AS Diff 
from staff 
where salary >=(select AVG(salary) from staff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select name,salary-avg(select avg(salary) from staff) as Difference from staff where salary>=(select avg(salary) from staff);